# How to use Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite in xamarin with full linking? (Link user Assemblies)

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, linker, entity-framework-core, android-r8

A made a Xamarin form app, now i'm trying t make a distribution version for Android (target api 29. minimum 23). Work fine when link sdk assemblies only active, but not work in full linking, app crash on startup.

I got exception  ([Full excetion](https://pastebin.com/PhSvcDye))  You can see DatabaseHelper in exception [link](https://pastebin.com/wZhKVPNE)

`System.InvalidOperationException: A suitable constructor for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Diagnostics.Internal.SqliteLoggingDefinitions' could not be located. Ensure the`

or

`System.InvalidOperationException: A suitable constructor for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.Internal.DbConnectionInterceptorAggregator' could not be located. Ensure the`

My context

```
[Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
    public class meAppDatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        private const string databaseName = "dummy.db";
        public virtual DbSet<..> ..{ get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            string databasePath = "";
            switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
            {
                case Device.iOS:
                    Batteries_V2.Init();
                    databasePath = ath.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "..",
                        "Library", databaseName);              
                    break;
                case Device.Android:
                    databasePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, databaseName);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException("Platform not supported");
            }
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Filename={databasePath}");
        }
    }
```

I tried to add proguard.cfg

```
-keep public class Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.**
-keep public class Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.**
-keep public class Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Diagnostics.Internal.SqliteLoggingDefinitions
-keep public class Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.Internal.DbConnectionInterceptorAggregator
```

i tried to create LinkerDescription.xml

```
<linker>
    <assembly fullname="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore">
        <type fullname="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.SqliteLoggingDefinitions"></type>
        <type fullname="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbConnectionInterceptorAggregator"></type>
...
```

I tried to add AndroidLinkSkip

```
<AndroidLinkSkip>
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Diagnostics.Internal.SqliteLoggingDefinitions;
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.Internal.DbConnectionInterceptorAggregator;
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite;
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
</AndroidLinkSkip>
```

I tried to use in MainActivity.cs and App.cs

```
var a = typeof(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.Internal.DbConnectionInterceptorAggregator);
var b = typeof(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Diagnostics.Internal.SqliteLoggingDefinitions);
var c= typeof(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.SingletonOptionsInitializer);
```

Tried to call in mainactivity.cs

```
 Batteries_V2.Init();
```

Any tipp?

Latest VS19 community, and VS19 enterprise preview, all package up to date (i tried preview entytyfreamwork and sqlite package, same problem).  Netstandard 2.1
R8+D8

Comment: Please try to set the Linker to `None` to make a test, if it worked as normal, If you insisted set the Linker to `Link user Assemblies`, you could try to add   `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Diagnostics.Internal` in skip linking assemblies like this thread: https://imgur.com/a/bN3YQ2p

Comment: Did you test the application in Release mode on a physical device? not the emulator.

Comment: If the linker is None the app working. 
My biggest AndroidSkiplink conent which i tried [link](https://pastebin.com/dBmRrEiD)

Comment: Yes, in huawei p30 and mi A1 phone.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue, you can open an support ticket(not free) for it. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportforbusiness/productselection?sapId=211dd84f-3474-c3c5-79bf-66db630c92a6

Comment: Same problem in this example app https://medium.com/codechem/using-entityframework-core-and-sqlite-with-xamarin-forms-45de7a926b71